# Using 'substr', how do you make the 'stop' mark stop at the last number in a line?

Tags: r, substring

Using 'substr', how do you make the 'stop' mark stop at the last number and not a specific character? Or what should I be using instead to do this function?

I am starting off with multiple csv files that need to have the text changed into columns. It looks like this (sorry, I know this isn't code but I don't know how to attach my csv files).

```
Total time  10:00.56
Lap times
01      00:06.08      00:06.08
02      00:06.89      00:00.81
03      00:13.36      00:06.47
04      00:16.04      00:02.68
05      00:17.11      00:01.07
06      00:24.52      00:07.41
07      00:31.85      00:07.33
08      00:33.80      00:01.95
09      00:45.96      00:12.16
10      00:47.34      00:01.38
11      01:01.07      00:13.73
12      01:06.94      00:05.87
13      01:19.54      00:12.60
14      01:20.16      00:00.62
15      01:26.49      00:06.33
16      01:27.07      00:00.58
17      01:34.89      00:07.82
18      01:37.72      00:02.83
19      01:57.95      00:20.23
20      02:10.92      00:12.97
```

Here is the code I am using to to organize the data. Basically, I split the data from one column into two then I split the data by every other line and find the total number of lines in the split.

```
library(chron)
library(tidyr)
library( plyr )
wd = "C:/Users/callej03/Desktop/test"
files = list.files(path=wd, pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE, 
recursive=FALSE)

df.list = lapply(files, function(x) {
dat = read.csv(x, header= TRUE) 
dat = dat[-c(1),]
dat = as.data.frame(dat)
dat = separate(data = dat, col = dat, into = c("lap", "duration"), sep = "\\    
")
dat$count = 1:nrow(dat) 
y = dat$count
i= y%%2==0
dat$interacting = i
int = dat[which(dat$interacting == TRUE),]
interactions = sum(int$interacting)
})

df.list = as.data.frame(df.list)
df.list = t(df.list)
colnames(df.list) = c("# of interactions")
row.names(df.list) = sub(wd, "", files)
```

After that I use this code to change the row names according to the number listed in the csv name. So I get "1" as the row name instead of "/1.csv"

```
rownames(df.list) = substr(rownames(df.list),2,2)
```

This however only works for numbers 0 to 9. How could I make the "stop" mark look for all numbers?

Comment: You probably don't want to use `substr` for this, you want to use a regular expression. You can use `gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", rownames(df.list))` to extract just the numbers.

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Esther, this code worked!

```
row.names(df.list) = gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", rownames(df.list))
```

...and then I used this code to get rid of the "/" in the row name so that I would only get the numbers.

```
row.names(df.list) = gsub('/', "", row.names(df.list), fixed = TRUE)
```